# Saving array with UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3, ios10, userdefaults

Is this the right way to save array of dictionaries in tableView using UserDefaults in Swift 3?
var arrNotes = [String:String]

```
func saveNotesArray () {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(arrNotes, forKey: "notes")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: Yes its correct

Comment: But what does the "forKey: "notes"" mean?

Comment: @Jovan Milosavljevic it is swift syntax to store object in userdefault using key.

Comment: `[String:String]` is not an array, by the way... And you don't need `.synchronize()`.

Comment: Using notes key you will get the object: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notes") as? [String:String]

Comment: @Eric Aya correct sir

Comment: forKey: "notes" its is a Key to save the data in that Key like in Dictionary and after later if you you want to fetch data again then with the help of this key you can get(fetch) data from userDefault

Comment: @DheerajD I am saving UITextView and I made array of dictionaries [["title" : "" , "body" : ""]] , but it doesn't save anything

Comment: Ok.. got it...  You are doing it in right way. you can get details using: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notes") as? [String:String]

Comment: Have you try fetching fetching details like above?

Comment: @EricAya it is my mistake it is a array of dictionaries [[String:String]]()

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get your notes:

```
 func saveNotesArray () {
       var notes = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notes") as?   [String:String]
}
```

Are you getting object in same way?

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift-3, the following way to Saving array with UserDefaults :**

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

userDefaults.set(arrayOfname, forKey:"Keyname")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: Can I put my project here, because I can't find a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

"[String: String]" Means a dictionary where the keys and the values are Strings.

"[[String: String]]" Means an array that contains dictionaries where the keys and values are strings.

create a dictionary of string and an array to hold them

```
let dictionary: [String: String] = ["keyOne" : "valueOne", "keyTwo": "valueTwo"]
let arrayWithDictionaryOfStrings: [[String: String]] = [dictionary]
```

add the array to userDefaults

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
userDefaults.set(arrayWithDictionaryOfStrings, forKey: "arrayWithDictionaryOfStrings")

userDefaults.synchronize();
```

get the array of dictionaries from the userdefaults

```
if let fetchedArrayWithDictionaryOfStrings: [[String: String]] = (userDefaults.object(forKey: "arrayWithDictionaryOfStrings") as? [[String: String]]) {
    // handle fetchedArrayWithDictionaryOfStrings
}
```

Comment: You don't need `.synchronize()`.

Comment: @Eric Aya, that depends. "Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes."  https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Comment: Yeah I know this document, *that's why I'm telling you* that you don't need `.synchronize()`...! It is "automatically invoked at periodic intervals" and that's enough for 99,99% of the cases, like here.

Answer (score 0):

your should  do it like This 
**For Saving**

```
let placesData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: placesArray)
UserDefaults.standard.set(arrNotes, forKey: "notes")
```

**To Retrieved array from NSUserDefault.**

```
let placesData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notes") as? NSData

if let placesData = placesData {
    let arrNotes = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: placesData as Data) as? NSMutableArray
    print(arrNotes)
```

}