# How to store NSArray in Userdefaults?

Tags: json, swift, userdefaults

Here is my code

```
var defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard
var json = NSArray()
self.defaultValues.set(json, forKey: "BedData")
```

I used this Code to store Strings and it works perfectly but when i tried to store NSArray it gives me this error "Attempt to insert non-property list object"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving array with UserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441446/saving-array-with-userdefaults)

Comment: First of all do not use `NSArray` in Swift. It lacks type information. The contents of the array must be property list compliant, for example `[String]()` will work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode and decode for adding and retrieving data to/from UserDefault.

```
func getUserDetail() -> UserDetail? {
    if let decodedData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: AppConstant.userDefaultKey.user_detail) as? Data {
        return try! PropertyListDecoder().decode(UserDetail.self, from: decodedData)
    }
    return nil
}

func setUserDetail(user: UserDetail) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(try! PropertyListEncoder().encode(user), forKey: AppConstant.userDefaultKey.user_detail)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies Guys But i have found the solution

```
Let json = NSArray()
```

To Store

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: json)
            self.defaultValues.set(data, forKey: "Offline-BedData")
```

And to Retrieve:

```
if let data = self.defaultValues.object(forKey: "Offline-BedData")! as? Data {

                if let dict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? NSArray {
                    json = dict
                    print("json\(json)")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BedShow", sender: Any?.self)
                }
            }
```